# C# Subracting Inputted Textbox Value to the Label value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building these POS Desktop application in Windows form and it's almost done but i'm having problem in processing the customer bills.

To be specific:
SIMSProduct Usercontrol

- cart.lbl_price.Text = lbl_totalprice.Text;
  First the total of the customer bought is in lbl_totalprice.Text
  Next that total is used to ProcessCart Form which is the cart.lbl_price.Text
- lbl_price.Text is now successfully getting the value of lbl_totalprice.Text

ProcessCart Form

- txt_amount(Textbox) is where user input the pay value of customer that should be subracted to the lbl_price.Text which is fail.
- lbl_totalprice.Text corresponds to the output of subracted lbl_price and txt_amount which is fail too

Note: lbl corresponds to Windows form Label

The problem is when i tried to input to my txt_amount, let's say i input 5000 and that 5000 is not subracting the value of lbl_price, also the lbl_totalprice is equal to what i type to txt_amount. Below these code, What I've done wrong here ?, something that i should not made? or i forgot something ?. I hope someone would be able to help in these matter. Thank you

```
    public partial class SIMSProduct : UserControl
{
    ITEMCount item;
    ProcessCart cart;
    public SIMSProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

 private void btn_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cart = new ProcessCart();
        cart.Show();
        cart.lbl_price.Text = lbl_totalprice.Text; 
    }
}

public partial class ProcessCart : Form
{     
    public ProcessCart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void txt_amount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value1;
        int value2;
        decimal value3;
        if (int.TryParse(lbl_price.Text.Trim(), out value1))
        {
            Total = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_price.Text);            
        }
        if (int.TryParse(txt_amount.Text.Trim(), out value2))
        {

            Paid = Convert.ToInt32(txt_amount.Text);          
        }
        lbl_totalprice.Text = (Paid - Total).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit poor. You're parsing labels. You should avoid that. Keep the values as `decimal` fields in your class - don't populate and parse labels.

Comment: I updated it , to your suggestion can you give an example of that

Comment: Does https://dotnetfiddle.net/oG9psB give you the idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is a casting issue. Looks like you're attempting to cast a decimal to an integer value. Try replacing with this code.

```
    public partial class SIMSProduct : UserControl
{
    ITEMCount item;
    ProcessCart cart;
    public SIMSProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

 private void btn_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cart = new ProcessCart();
        cart.Show();
        cart.lbl_price.Text = lbl_totalprice.Text; 
    }
}

public partial class ProcessCart : Form
{     
    public ProcessCart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void txt_amount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal value1;
        decimal value2;
        decimal value3;
        if (decimal.TryParse(lbl_price.Text.Trim(), out value1))
        {
            Total = Convert.ToDecimal(lbl_price.Text);            
        }
        if (decimal.TryParse(txt_amount.Text.Trim(), out value2))
        {

            Paid = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_amount.Text);          
        }
        if (decimal.TryParse(lbl_totalprice.Text.Trim(), out value3))
        {
            Change = Convert.ToDecimal(lbl_totalprice.Text);
        }
        Change = Paid - Total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Did you mean should i parse it as integer instead of decimal ?

Comment: No you're assigning Total an integer value instead of decimal but then later on you attempt to do math on it. Change = Paid - Total; (Decimal = Decimal - Integer;) When you need them all to be the same Decimal = Decimal - Decimal; Then if you look, you declared "Value1" as a decimal.. so it appears to just be a mismatch.

Comment: I tried to used debugger here, lbl_price.Text  shows the value lbl_totalprice  and txt_amount shows the inputted value of mine

Comment: So, What should i change or What should be remove ?

Comment: I tried to convert as integer but it doesn't work. See above is already updated

Comment: You're still doing the same thing. You need everything to be the same data type

Comment: @xTwisteDx decimal = decimal - integer is perfectly fine arithmetic for C#. `decimal x = 25.34M; int y = 9; decimal z = x - y; Console.WriteLine(z); // Output 16.34`

Comment: Bad practice to be doing that when it involves monetary values right? @JonathonChase

Comment: @xTwisteDx I'm not sure where you got that idea.

Comment: @JonathonChase then how can he do this. Change (Decimal) = Price (Decimal) - Total (Integer) whenever that "Total" might be 2.20, he's dealing with monetary values. I'm assuming since it's a POS system everything is in 000.00 format.

Comment: @Anonymous can you give me an example of an input? I seen your edit request but I'm still not thinking that it's correct to be using integer values like that. Do you have any inputs that are 5000.25 or any decimal value?

Comment: @xTwisteDx I'm not saying the logic isn't off, just that there's nothing inherently incorrect with subtracting an integer from a decimal. Integers probably make more sense for an _amount_ than for a price or total. Trying to `Convert.ToInt32("2.20");` will immediately throw a `FormatException`, so it wouldn't get to the operation as is. Instead of calling Convert in the first place, you should probably just use the value created by the TryParse.

Comment: Now i know why it doesn't subtract , it doesn't get the actual value of lbl_totalprice.Text to lbl_price.. i tried to messagebox it if he's getting the value but messagebox doesn't show

Comment: Have you tried using math on Value3 = Value2  - Value1;